# I am using Parse.com and nodejs for user authentication, but everyone is the same user

Tags: node.js, authentication, parse-platform

I am using the [node parse package](http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/11/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/) to perform user authentication on the server. However, once a single user logs in, every visitor to the website is authenticated as that user.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cf. https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp-users

> User Session Management
>
> You can add Parse.User authentication and session management to your Express app using the parseExpressCookieSession middleware. You just need to call Parse.User.logIn() in Cloud Code, and this middleware will automatically manage the user session for you.
>
> You can use a web form to ask for the user's login credentials, and log in the user in Cloud Code when you receive data from this form. After you call Parse.User.logIn(), this middleware will automatically set a cookie in the user's browser. During subsequent HTTP requests from the same browser, this middleware will use this cookie to automatically set the current user in Cloud Code. This will make ACLs work properly in Cloud Code, and allow you to retrieve the entire current user object if needed. Finally, when you log out a user in Cloud Code by calling Parse.User.logOut(), this middleware will automatically remove the browser cookie. For sample app code, please see the documentation for this middleware.
>
> When you work with user data, you should use HTTPS whenever possible. To protect your app and your users, the parseExpressCookieSession middleware requires you to use HTTPS. For your convenience, we also provide a parseExpressHttpsRedirect middleware for redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS. Please see its documentation for details.

Comment: https://github.com/flovilmart/parse-express-cookie-session `npm install --save parse-express-cookie-session` should work

Comment: You need to explain what is really going on to address the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Because of the nature of parse and nodejs, parse stores the user in such a way that it is authenticated to your node instance, not the client. To get around this, make use of the user token provided by parse, sessions, and the .become() method in the Parse user object.

I chose to use [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) for sessions.

When your user logs in:

```
parse = require('parse').Parse
parse.initialize([ your key ], [ your other key ])

parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password, {
    success: function(user) {
        req.session.token = user._sessionToken
        [ whatever you want to do here]
    },
    error: function(error) {
        [ handle your error ]
    }
})
```

On every page load:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    parse = require('parse').Parse
    parse.initialize([ your key ], [ your other key ])
    parse.User.become(req.session.token ? req.session.token: "gibberish").then(function(user) { // If null is passed to .become() it will assume current(), which we don't want
        [ user is now the client authenticated user ]
    })
})
```

logout:

```
parse = require('parse').Parse
parse.initialize([ your key ], [ your other key ])

parse.User.logOut()
req.session = null
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the stuff @lordscarlet . It matters to know how things work rather than simply getting a link to GIT repo...

Comment: After calling parse.user.logIn I don't see _sessionToken in user. Anyone else not see it?

Comment: I don't see it either, @asiammyself. Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: @asiammyself, Using user.getSessionToken(); instead, worked for me.